# CSS Styling Overridden

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I am having issues with my styling for a landing page on SharePoint.

SharePoint loves to write over HTML with its own which makes the styling a bit funky.

There are a few table elements that appear with the element selector in the developer tools on the page, but I do not believe those are interfering with my custom HTML. There are two s that appear and I believe is messing with my HTML/CSS. They are both `#s4-bodyContainer`  & `#contentRow`. The more I look at it it seems that the #s4-bodyContainer is the one it will not fill. I have changed the margin of it to 0, as well as the width to 100% and the content still will not cover the whole width/height of the containing div?

Here is my relevant HTML/CSS:

```css
header {
    text-align:center;
    background: #104723;
    overflow:auto;
}
.flexbox-container {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
}
#s4-bodyContainer {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#s4-workspace{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
footer {
    background: #104723;
    color: #104723;
    height: 85px;
    width: 100%;
}
.headhead {
    color: white;
}  
.flexbox-container > * {
    flex:1;
    min-width:0;
    margin:0;
}
.tst{
    position: relative;
}
.troopers {
    max-width:100%;
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 5px #000);
}
button {
    display:block;
    margin-top:50px; 
}
.black {
    font-size:25px;
    color: #104723;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.logo {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.gold {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #b3ab7d;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.btn-group .button {
    background-color: #104723;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #b3ab7d;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.selector {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .selector .btnselect {
    background-color: #104723;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #b3ab7d;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
  .item-select {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .item-select a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .item-select a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }
  
  .selector:hover .item-select {
    display: block;
  }
  #sideNavBox { DISPLAY: none }
  #contentBox { margin-left: 0 }
  
.flexbox-container {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example Landing Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        </head>
    <body>
        <!--<header>
            <h1 class="headhead">Active Projects</h1>
        </header>-->
        <div class="flexbox-container">
            <div class="tst">
                <img class="troopers" src="https://www.usxjobs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/TROOPERS-2a.png" alt="troopers"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="black">Welcome to the Projects Site</h1>
                <h1 class="gold">Insert Sample Text</h1>
                <div class="selector">
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btnselect">Site 1
                     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                   </button></a>
                   <div class="item-select">
                       <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 1</a>
                       <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 2</a>
                       <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 3</a>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="selector">
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btnselect">Site 2 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                      </button></a>
                      <div class="item-select">
                          <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 1</a>
                          <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 2</a>
                          <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 3</a>
                          <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 4</a>
                          <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 5</a>
                      </div>
                      </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <img src="" class="logo"/>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what they look like on page:
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. I don't see `#s4-bodyContainer` in your html 2. Is your custom css included after `SharePoint` css?

Comment: @MrT yes it is included in the computed CSS after the page has loaded. there is no #s4-bodyContainer in my HTML because as I mentioned that is generated by the SharePoint page and has nothing to do with my HTML, yet it is effecting it.

Comment: @BeerusDev Is this a custom SitePage that you are referring to or the entire master-page layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep swipe of anything on the internet that could remotely helpful to this issue, I finally came across a similar topic on the MSDN :

The solution says to implement this:

```
  .ms-webpartPage-root{
border-spacing:0px!important;
}
```

And it works!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the CSS rules for the `#s4-bodyContainer` on SharePoint are not inline (from external file: corev15.css). Meaning you should be able to override them if you attach your CSS at the end of the master-page body. If it doesn't work you can resort to the `!important` tag to give your CSS properties precedence. checkout [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: This was implemented to the page from a script editor. I have worked with the master pages before to implement a custom header that goes across all sites, but I believe this is achievable without having to mess with the master page?

Comment: Yes, if that's the case there should be no harm in overriding the margin set by default. Since it's only for that page.

Answer (score 1):

Using ! important doesn't always fixes the issue. The problem basically with ! important is perhaps your styling library might also be using it. So try checking whether your margin and width property is being applied to that specific section through Google inspector or any other browser inspector. Try checking whether your styling software has made a property called max-width and whether it is being applied. And most of all if a little modification and fidlling with ! important doesn't work. Go for inline css..

Answer (score 1):

That is an issue with space if image is used as original inline-element like an text element. Solution:

Just add
`display:block;` to `.troopers`
See example!

(Alternative: set `line-height: 0; font-size: 0` to wrapper of image `div.tst`. That avoid unwhanted space from text effects as well.)

```css
header {
    text-align:center;
    background: #104723;
    overflow:auto;
}
.flexbox-container {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
}
#s4-bodyContainer {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#s4-workspace{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
footer {
    background: #104723;
    color: #104723;
    height: 85px;
    width: 100%;
}
.headhead {
    color: white;
}  
.flexbox-container > * {
    flex:1;
    min-width:0;
    margin:0;
}
.tst{
    position: relative;
}
.troopers {
    /* ADD ... */
    display: block;
    max-width:100%;
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 5px #000);
}
button {
    display:block;
    margin-top:50px; 
}
.black {
    font-size:25px;
    color: #104723;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.logo {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.gold {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #b3ab7d;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.btn-group .button {
    background-color: #104723;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #b3ab7d;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.selector {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .selector .btnselect {
    background-color: #104723;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #b3ab7d;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
  .item-select {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .item-select a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .item-select a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }
  
  .selector:hover .item-select {
    display: block;
  }
  #sideNavBox { DISPLAY: none }
  #contentBox { margin-left: 0 }
  
.flexbox-container {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example Landing Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        </head>
    <body>
        <!--<header>
            <h1 class="headhead">Active Projects</h1>
        </header>-->
        <div class="flexbox-container">
            <div class="tst">
                <img class="troopers" src="https://www.usxjobs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/TROOPERS-2a.png" alt="troopers"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="black">Welcome to the Projects Site</h1>
                <h1 class="gold">Insert Sample Text</h1>
                <div class="selector">
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btnselect">Site 1
                     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                   </button></a>
                   <div class="item-select">
                       <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 1</a>
                       <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 2</a>
                       <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 3</a>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="selector">
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btnselect">Site 2 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                      </button></a>
                      <div class="item-select">
                          <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 1</a>
                          <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 2</a>
                          <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 3</a>
                          <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 4</a>
                          <a href="" target="_blank">Sub 5</a>
                      </div>
                      </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <img src="" class="logo"/>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: None of the following answers have worked so far.